# Getting an exception on server after deployment

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am getting an below Exception on Page load:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$main$txtPreviewOfFile="...y Teacher <PR+OJ>             ..."). 
Description: ASP.NET has detected data in the request that is potentially dangerous because it might include HTML markup or script. The data might represent an attempt to compromise the security of your application, such as a cross-site scripting attack. If this type of input is appropriate in your application, you can include code in a web page to explicitly allow it. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=212874. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$main$txtPreviewOfFile="...y Teacher <PR+OJ>             ...").
```

An error coming after deployment on server but not on Visual Studio even I am trying to find the exception with Visual studio web application is working fine.

I have used `validateRequest="false"` and `requestValidationMode="2.0"` but after using these tags in `web.config` or on `page directive` exception is get ride-off but the page functionality stopped working.

Please help me with the exception.

Comment: `ctl00$main$txtPreviewOfFile` => this indicates textbox server control named `txtPreviewOfFile` inside content placeholder. Can you provide page markup (and related code behind)?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Thanx for your help and Exception has been resolved to using Server.HtmlEncode method
`txtPreviewOfFile.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(preview.ToString());`

Thanx again to point out the exception area. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `Server.HtmlEncode()` Method to Encode the html tags into textbox

```
txtPreviewOfFile.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(preview.ToString());
```